# enviar 2 variáveis pela url

Tags: php, mysql

Envio 2 `variáveis` pela `url`:

```
var http = false;
http = new XMLHttpRequest();

function carrega(){

   var nome = document.getElementById('CodigoUtente').value;
   var nomes = document.getElementById('Nome').value;

   var url_="conexao4?CodigoUtente="+nome+"&Nome="+nomes;
   http.open("GET",url_,true);
   http.onreadystatechange=function(){
      if(http.readyState==4){

         var retorno = JSON.parse(http.responseText);

         document.getElementById('CodigoUtente').value = retorno.CodigoUtente;
         document.getElementById('Nome').value = retorno.Nome;
         document.getElementById('DataNasc').value = retorno.DataNasc;
         document.getElementById('Sexo').value = retorno.Sexo;
         document.getElementById('Estadocivil').value = retorno.Estadocivil;
         document.getElementById('Nacionalidade').value = retorno.Nacionalidade;
         document.getElementById('Responsavel').value = retorno.Responsavel;
         document.getElementById('Parentesco').value = retorno.Parentesco;
         document.getElementById('Contato').value = retorno.Contato;
      }
   }
   http.send(null);

}
```

na página conexao4 tenho o php que recebe as variáveis:

```
$CodigoUtente = $_GET['CodigoUtente'];
$Nome = $_GET['Nome'];

if((isset($CodigoUtente)) && (isset($Nome))){  

   $sql = "SELECT CodigoUtente, Nome, DataNasc, Sexo, Estadocivil, Nacionalidade, Responsavel, Parentesco, Contato FROM centrodb.PsicUtentes WHERE (CodigoUtente = '$CodigoUtente') OR (Nome = '%$Nome%')";

   $resultados = $conn->query($sql);

   $json = array();

   while ($rowResultados = $resultados->fetch_assoc()) {

      $dados = array(
         'CodigoUtente' => $rowResultados['CodigoUtente'],
         'Nome' => $rowResultados['Nome'],
         'DataNasc' => $rowResultados['DataNasc'],
         'Sexo' => $rowResultados['Sexo'],
         'Estadocivil' => $rowResultados['Estadocivil'],
         'Nacionalidade' => $rowResultados['Nacionalidade'],
         'Responsavel' => $rowResultados['Responsavel'],
         'Parentesco' => $rowResultados['Parentesco'],
         'Contato' => $rowResultados['Contato']
      );
      $json = $dados;

   }

echo json_encode($json);

}
```

O problema é que só funcionam se preencher os dois `inputs` e pretendia que retornassem os dados da base de dados só ao preencher uma delas.

**Estou a tentar resolver desta forma, mas continua a retornar sempre a última linha da tabela:**

```
$where_caluse = array();
$CodigoUtente = $_GET['CodigoUtente'];
$Nome = $_GET['Nome'];

if(isset($_GET['CodigoUtente'])){
  $where_caluse[] = "CodigoUtente = '".$_GET['CodigoUtente']."'";    
}

if(isset($_GET['Nome'])){
  $where_caluse[] =  "Nome = '".$_GET['Nome']."'";  
}

$where = array_filter($where_caluse);

$query = "SELECT CodigoUtente, Nome, DataNasc, Sexo, Estadocivil, Nacionalidade, Responsavel, Parentesco, Contato FROM centrodb.PsicUtentes";

$resultados = $conn->query($query);

if(!empty($where)){

$final_where = count($where) > 1 ? implode(' OR ', $where) : end($where);
$query = "$query WHERE ". $final_where;

$json = array();

while ($rowResultados = $resultados->fetch_assoc()) {

  $dados = array(
     'CodigoUtente' => $rowResultados['CodigoUtente'],
     'Nome' => $rowResultados['Nome'],
     'DataNasc' => $rowResultados['DataNasc'],
     'Sexo' => $rowResultados['Sexo'],
     'Estadocivil' => $rowResultados['Estadocivil'],
     'Nacionalidade' => $rowResultados['Nacionalidade'],
     'Responsavel' => $rowResultados['Responsavel'],
     'Parentesco' => $rowResultados['Parentesco'],
     'Contato' => $rowResultados['Contato']
    );
      $json = $dados;
}
echo json_encode($json);

}
```

Comment: Você já não havia [perguntado isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/358818/enviar-2-vari%C3%A1veis-pela-url)? Por que excluiu e perguntou novamente?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá, criei 3 condições para que caso os valores da variável `$Nome` `$CodigoUtente` não exista oa query de adeque a sua consulta, basicamente foram alguns ifs que determinavam se a `query` teria ou não as condições do where:

Página conexao4

```
$CodigoUtente = $_GET['CodigoUtente'];
$Nome = $_GET['Nome'];

// Verficando se os dois parametros foram pasados, 
if(($Nome != "") && ($CodigoUtente != "")){
    $sql_where = "WHERE (CodigoUtente = '$CodigoUtente') OR (Nome = '%$Nome%')";    
} else if ($CodigoUtente != ""){
    $sql_where = "WHERE (CodigoUtente = '$CodigoUtente')";    
}else if ($Nome != ""){
    $sql_where = "WHERE (Nome = '%$Nome%')";        
} else {
    // sem nada aqui porque não fez uma busca e sim quer listar todos, é opicional
    $sql_where = "";
}



if((isset($CodigoUtente)) && (isset($Nome))){  

    $sql = "SELECT CodigoUtente, Nome, DataNasc, Sexo, Estadocivil, Nacionalidade, Responsavel, Parentesco, Contato FROM centrodb.PsicUtentes ".$sql_where;    

   $resultados = $conn->query($sql);

   $json = array();

   while ($rowResultados = $resultados->fetch_assoc()) {

      $dados = array(
         'CodigoUtente' => $rowResultados['CodigoUtente'],
         'Nome' => $rowResultados['Nome'],
         'DataNasc' => $rowResultados['DataNasc'],
         'Sexo' => $rowResultados['Sexo'],
         'Estadocivil' => $rowResultados['Estadocivil'],
         'Nacionalidade' => $rowResultados['Nacionalidade'],
         'Responsavel' => $rowResultados['Responsavel'],
         'Parentesco' => $rowResultados['Parentesco'],
         'Contato' => $rowResultados['Contato']
      );
      $json = $dados;

   }

echo json_encode($json);

}
```

A lógica aplicada foi, caso tenha Nome somente ele buscara apenas por nome, caso tenha só o código cliente ele buscara apenas por código cliente e caso tenha ambos ele irar buscar por um ou outro.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: assim já funciona, só tem um problema. O problema é se pesquisar por exemplo pelo codigoutente 255 só consigo fazer nova pesquisa por um codigoutente superior, por exemplo se for um codigoutente mais pequeno, por exemplo o 151, não retorna os dados do novo utente que pesquisei, mas se for o 452 já retorna.

Comment: Rapaz eu não entendi bem, quando você busca por um numero, e depois faz uma nova busca só funciona caso o `codigoutente` seja maior ?

Comment: sim. Depois de fazer a primeira pesquisa, só consigo fazer novamente caso o codigoutente seja maior do que o anterior, se for menor não funciona.

Comment: faz o teste pra mim faz a busca e coloca um numero numero e ve se esse numero vai ser enviado na url como um numero menor, ou se vai manter o mesmo numero.

Comment: Rapais testar com essa correção que eu fiz, acabei invertendo o SQL dentro do where

Comment: para funcionar já tinha invertido o sql dentro do where, porque senão recebia undefined nos inputs

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88948/discussion-between-iniciante-and-bulfaitelo).

Answer (score 1):

Prezado,
Você terá que fazer um tratamento na variável $sql, verificando se os parâmetros foram ou não informados, para então concatenar...

Algo assim:

```
$sql = "SELECT CodigoUtente, Nome, DataNasc, Sexo, Estadocivil, Nacionalidade, Responsavel, Parentesco, Contato FROM centrodb.PsicUtentes WHERE 1 = 1 ";

if($CodigoUtente != "" )
     $sql .= "AND (CodigoUtente = '$CodigoUtente') ";

if($Nome != "")
     $sql .= "AND (Nome = '%$Nome%')";
```

Coloquei como AND pois ele só entrará na query caso realmente tenha sido informado, precisará de alguns ajustes caso queira realmente que seja um OR (ajustar com chaves)